# How can I set the text in a TextView to a String (AndriodStudio)?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have seen a lot of responses saying to use `getResources().getString(R.string.coupon_1)` to get the String from the **strings.xml** file and change it, but it continues to show the value in the **strings.xml** file for me instead of showing the String in coupon1, coupon2, or coupon3.

This is part of my method with some things I have tried:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coupon, container, false);

        couponListTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.couponListTextView);
        couponItem1TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.couponItem1TextView);
        couponItem2TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.couponItem2TextView);
        couponItem3TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.couponItem3TextView);

//        coupon1 = "Is";
//        coupon2 = "this";
//        coupon3 = "working?";

        //coupon1 = getResources().getString(R.string.coupon_1);
        coupon1 = "Is";
        couponItem1TextView.setText(coupon1);
        //coupon2 = getResources().getString(R.string.coupon_2);
        coupon2 = "this";
        couponItem2TextView.setText(coupon2);
        //coupon3 = getResources().getString(R.string.coupon_3);
        coupon3 = "working?";
        couponItem3TextView.setText(coupon3);

        CouponRequest couponRequest = new CouponRequest(coupon1, coupon2, coupon3, responseListener, errorListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(couponRequest);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coupon, container, false);
    }
```

These are my declarations in strings.xml:

```
<string name="coupon_1">No coupon</string>
<string name="coupon_2">No coupon</string>
<string name="coupon_3">No coupon</string>
```

These are my TextView declarations in fragment_coupon:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/couponItem1TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/couponListTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/couponItem2TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/coupon_2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/couponItem1TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/couponItem3TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/coupon_3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/couponItem2TextView" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The strings I am using here are for the purpose of testing the app. I really need to be able to write using a string whose value is decided at runtime.

Edit: I figured it out. I just needed to return view instead of creating a new instance of View.

Answer (score 1):

A string is a simple resource that is referenced using the value provided in the name attribute.
So all lines that you use should be in `strings.xml`.

```
<string name="no_coupon">No coupon</string>
<string name="is">Is</string>
<string name="this">this</string>
<string name="working">working?</string>
```

And as I understand it, your `TextView` are initially set by the string `No coupon`.
So in `.xml` file `TextView` should have `android:text="@string/no_coupon"`

And in method `onCreateView` you can change text, using method `setText()`.
For example, `couponItem1TextView.setText(R.string.is);`

Comment: If I could solve your problem, please mark my answer as a solution.